# Sentence with 'issue' and 'issue': Is it even grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Does this make sense and is this grammatical?

> It’s a very difficult issue to push because of the issue that security comes first.
>
> -- *The Accidental Victims of Morsi's Fall*, [New Yorker, September 2013](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/newsdesk/2013/09/the-accidental-syrian-victims-of-morsis-fall.html)

Comment: What does it mean? I have a feeling that "issue" is used wrong here.

Comment: The sentence refers to two different issues. The first is the legitimacy of Syrian refugees in Cairo, the second is concern for the safety of the citizens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence does make sense but it's not particularly well written. It doesn't flow as the word issue is used twice.

Comment: so the "that" after "the fact" is the same as "the fact that the world is not peaceful is a truism.?"

Comment: @kih1930 the questions that come out of ELL! I'd say yes to that.